# Is saying "There would be no rich without the poor" a false dichotomy?

Tags: logic, fallacies

It seems that a lot of people try to conclude the "inevitable truth" from this argument, as if there would not be a chance for being rich without poverty. With rich and poor I'm referring to a persons wealth.

While researching this issue I came across **binary opposition**, which as per my understanding defines two opposites that depend on each other so that for example without people being poor we would not be able to understand the notion rich (and vice versa). With this definition it seems like this saying wouldn't be a false dilemma, as there would be no in between.

However can't one define those terms independently too? Poor could be defined as simply not having enough money/wealth to satisfy even the most basic needs like food, water, a house, while rich would be to have way more than enough to satisfy those needs. This would somewhat hint to a third option, which would be to have roughly enough money/wealth to satisfy ones needs. (Actually there suddenly arise a lot of in between, depending on how exact one categorizes people). Wouldn't the saying then be a false dilemma?

EDIT: typo

Comment: I'm not sure you could classify terms which are defined in contradistinction to each other as a false dilemma. They are both qualifiers of the category of "wealth" which will by necessity be comparative to some agreed upon baseline.

Comment: My https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7597/the-word-not-often-doesnt-mean-total-negation-in-mathematical-sense may or may not be helpful.

Comment: You can have differences in the level of wealth without the obscene levels of inequality seen today; inequality rocketed during the neo-liberal regime,

Comment: "Basic needs" are a vague and evolving concept, our stone age ancestors lived without much of what today is considered basic. UN established an [absolute poverty line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_poverty) in 1995, its official goal is to lift everybody above it. But when we succeed the notion of "needs" will probably shift again, along with the notions of "rich" and "poor".

Comment: If you have a dimension along which you measure values then it must have two ends. We live in a world of opposites. This is not a dilemma but just the way it is. If we some people were not poor we'd have no idea what we mean when we say some are wealthy. It's the same conceptual situation as hot-cold, left-right, good-evil etc.

Comment: @PeterJ. Only if what you are measuring is finite (not saying that wealth isn't finite). "This is the way it is" is a tautology so I don't count that as an argument. Also, like stated in the accepted answer, there are different kinds of opposites, wich this question ultimately boild down to. Gradable antonyms by definition don't exclude that you can be rich, poor OR something else (average). Just because poor people don't exist anymore doesn't suddenly take away my wealth. Note that I'm not asking "would the notion rich exist if poor NEVER even existed". That's something else entirely.

Comment: Categories demand that there be something outside the category. Thus all categories depend on being in opposition to a counter-category. Even the category 'not rich or poor' has the counter -category 'rich or poor'. It's how we think, by employing complementary and contradictory categories of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Rich' and 'poor' are mutually exclusive (one can't be both at the same time in the same respect). But one doesn't have to be one or the other - one can have a median position in respect to wealth. That's to say, neither rich nor poor but in the middle of the wealth distribution.

@Alessio Eberl. I don't think you need to prove that there is actually such a group of people as the medians. Conceptually it's enough to prove that logically there could be. 'Rich' and 'poor' are [contraries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Gradable_antonyms), not [contradictories](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Complementary_antonyms). If one is not rich it doesn't mean one is poor; there's at least a third possibility, namely that one is of median wealth. (Whether medians exist is an economic question, nothing to do with conceptual analysis.)  Why assume that rich/ poor is a dichotomy ?  'True' and 'false' are dichotomies if one assumes bivalence - mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive. 'Rich' and 'poor' are nothing like this, just points on a continuum : rich at one end, poor at the other and other states of wealth in-between.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to say with my 2nd definition of poor vs rich. From Wikipedia:  [A dichotomy must be mutually exclusive **and** jointly exhaustive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy). That means if there's a third set of people besides poor and rich, which we both claimed to be "averag/middle", than it is in fact a false dichotomy because poor and rich aren't jointly exhaustve, am I correct? Now I'm asking myself how one proves that there is a 3rd set of people with "average" wealth, however that's probably a seperate question.

Comment: @Alessio Eberl. I don't think you need to prove that there is actually such a group of people as the medians. Conceptually it's enough to prove that logically there could be. 'Rich' and 'Poor' are contraries, not contradictories. If one is not rich it doesn't mean one is poor; there's at least a third possibility, namely that one is of median wealth. Whether medians exist is an economic question, nothing to do with conceptual analysis.

Comment: @Goeffrey Thomas Thanks that's _exactly_ what I wanted to know! Can you add this comment to your answer or can I edit it? The facts you stated (contraries vs contradictories) weren't obvious to me.

Comment: @Alessio Eberl. Yes, add whatever comment you want to !

Comment: Thansk, really great answer!

Comment: I edited your answer with corresponding links to a wikipedia article explaining the differences between gradable antonyms (contraries) and complementary antonyms (contradictories) as stated in your answer. I think this could be useful for people like me who didn't know about this linguistic difference before and need a starting point for researching this topic.

Comment: @Alessio Eberl. Your extra links will help people, so that's fine. Thanks for letting me know : GT.

Answer (score 2):

[Starhawk](http://starhawk.org/writing/books/truth-or-dare/) argues, from a basis in traditional pacifism and radical feminism, that rich and poor, even defined in terms of 'needs' remain a false dichotomy founded on an artificial notion of scarcity.  For her, this is the ultimate combined source and cause of our difficulty accounting the lasting costs of war and the value of care-giving in our society.

Without a constant fear of scarcity, we have no historical evidence that people measure their 'means' against their 'needs'.  Among various pre-modern cultures we see that although people have private property, they still share resources as they become available, even if the structure is time-based trading or other 'lightweight' versions similar to modern economy.  In such a culture, a community may be in good or bad stead, but it is not rich or poor, just currently lucky or unlucky.

One may plan to do the best with what is given, saving and managing resources. 
 But there is no objective measure of too much or not enough, because **needs are flexible** and can reduce as needed to survive difficulty or increase as allowed in a way that enables future austerity, and **value is relative** as different things are more or less available at different times.  When there is 'too much' or 'not enough', only an economic perspective sees this as a gap between resources and needs, because **neither of those can be honestly quantified**.  Other streams of history express these as periods where life is easy or difficult, and more or fewer people survive, not periods where groups or individuals are rich or poor.

What really matters in life is reduced to these two abstractions by this differentiation, which would not exist otherwise.  If we did not measure 'what matters' in this way, we would realize that a large quantity of what really keeps us alive is provided by discoveries, efforts and actions that take place outside the economy.  In those terms one may be both rich and poor simultaneously.  So in any honest accounting, there is no dichotomy here.

And while in economic theory this mismatch can be addressed through trade, giving us a single scale that is simply in flux, in reality we can attempt to control things like river courses or pollution, good or bad family culture, rising water and excess rain through markets and timely intervention.  But we ultimately fail.  In the U.S. even in Texas, one of our most conservative pro-market and anti-interventionist states, water rights are communal because you can be rich in everything else, and if someone sucks up all your water upstream, you are concurrently poor to the point you cannot survive a season.

Answer (score 1):

It's a false dichotomy because the emphasis, given today's world, is on the wrong aspect.

In the West generally, inequality has mushroomed to obscene levels. And it's a question of addressing this that is a key point in economics.

In the past this was addressed by progressive taxation and controls on rents and wages; collective bargaining power by the less affluent was strong and healthy because of the burgeoning labour movement and an esprit de corps that straddled all sectors of societies.

Today, since the onset of neoliberalism the labour movement has been crushed and society is more atomised than ever. Mary Midgely, a British philosopher observed her generation was lucky as they had an ideal that they could believe in. Today, it's only real-politick that is believed in and market mechanisms have penetrated all sectors of society and this is dangerously inimical to society itself. The proletariat has been rebranded the precariat and many of us find ourselves afloat in a very uncertain and bewildering world with many clues to a better world but few tools to enact change, real change and not the empty, vapid change that passes for real change today.

Your third option, that there is enough to go around is the key concept of redistributive economic justice. The question is getting there in an increasingly automated and automatic world. An idea that that's been kicking around recently is basic income which guarantees a basic income to every citizen that covers the basic neccesities of life. That might be a start. Apparently Finland has just embarked on a major study to see whether this can be made to work.

Comment: No, not "In the West generally". In the US, inequality declined substantially between 1920 and 1970 and has since increased substantially to around the same level as in 1920, depending on how you measure it. In Europe, inequality also declined between 1920 and 1970, and has since increased slightly, but to a level well short of the 1920s.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost more of an economics question, but I suppose it could be a philosophy or politics question too. It is indeed a false dichotomy. It would not be, if the economy were a closed environment and thus a zero sum game.

However, the sun gives the planet energy which humans can then use to expand the technosphere: the total system of all things created, used, and shared by humans, and there is a lot of energy available to us to use, for millions, if not hundreds of billions of years. Therefore one human does not have to diminish another person's wealth in order to gain wealth. People can work together to collectively increase wealth, through various methods, including reciprocity, consumerism, capitalism, and so on.

**Connection**

The connection between my answer and the question seems to have been  misunderstood, so let me try to explain it in better detail. Because economics is not a zero sum game, everyone can become "rich." **The existence of a "poor" group is not necessary in order for there to be a rich group and vise versa. Furthermore, neither "poor" or "rich" have to be defined in terms of the other.**

What does it mean to be poor? Economically, it means not having enough resources to reasonably survive, long term, without the immediate and constant aid of another. What does it mean to be rich? It means having enough resources in order to be able to do what you wish, without the need to expend additional energy in order to maintain that status.

Under these two definitions, it is clear that a society could be made up entirely of rich people. In this scenario, no one would need to work in order to "make a living." In order for such a society to exist, I think we would need to have a significant advancement in energy availability however. Such advancement could include efficient nuclear fusion, access to the currently theoretical and certainly debated "zero point energy," or some other form of yet to be discovered energy reservoir, as well as technology which would be able to efficiently translate that energy into production, such as a replicator.

**Dichotomy**

On the specific issue of dichotomy, while "poor" and "rich" do not need to be defined in terms of the other, and while we do not need poor people in order for there to be rich people, I would say that one cannot be both poor and rich. They are mutually exclusive. You can however be neither poor or rich. Both of these points follow from the definitions that I provided.

Comment: Your "zero sum game" argument is pretty interesting and actually explains the economical implications. However my question was more directed to the argumentative implications of such a saying and its analysis (See the accepted answer). Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Sorry; I guess I was not clear as to how my answer fits into your question. I edited the answer to make the connection more direct. Does that help, @AlessioEberl?

Comment: Thank you for elaborating! Your answer is valid in a economic context, wich I appreciate! However you could exchange rich and poor in my question with hot and cold, and the accepted answer would still hold, because both are [gradable antonyms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Gradable_antonyms), that means even though you can't be both at the same time (mutually exclusive), there are still lots of in betweens (**not** jointly exhaustive), thus failing to be a dichotomy by definition, in contrast to complementary antonyms. Should I edit my question to be more generic?

Comment: I was responding to the idea that there needs to be poor people in order for there to be rich people. As I stated in my answer, you do not need one for the other.

Comment: Yes and that is perfectly valid (and answers other questions I would have had) however my question was specifically about why the saying is not a dichotomy in a linguistic analytical sense, if you will. Your argument wouldn't be applicable to hot vs cold or slow vs fast etc. because it's too concrete, that's why I proposed to change my question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You had a few different questions it seems, including asking whether or not one needs to be defined in terms of the other. It does not, as I specifically explain. I think your question is really a few questions in one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70053/discussion-between-alessio-eberl-and-daniel-goldman).

Answer (score 0):

A false dichotomy would be something of the kind, "either someone is rich, or someone is poor". It is false because while one cannot be rich and poor at the same time (if we define "rich" and "poor" correctly), someone can be neither poor nor rich.

But this has nothing to do with what is asked in the title of this question, which is whether saying that there can be no rich without the poor is a false dichotomy. This is an independent issue, and I would say that such proposition is not a false dichotomy. It isn't even a dichotomy.

Let's apply this to another relation. Let's say that the issue involves slavery: "there can be no slavemasters without there being slaves". The truth of it is obvious: if there are no slaves, no one can own slaves, and consequently no one can be a slavemaster. It is still true that "either one is a slave, or a slavemaster" is a false dichotomy: most of us, living in the 21st century, are neither slaves nor slavemasters.

This is not true for all kinds of relation: for instance, it is false to say that there would be no Black people if there were no White people (perhaps nobody would notice skin colours in that case, but that is a differente issue). So the issue is to determine whether the poor-rich divide is of the same kind as the slave-master one, or, on the the contrary, it is of the Black-White kind.

As material wealth is both limited and quantifiable - as opposed to melanin - it would seem that one can only amass a significant amount of material wealth if others don't, and so that if someone is rich, then others are at least comparatively poor. Unless we define wealth and poverty differently, of course.

Comment: I think wealth does not depend on material wealth only, but on the ability to command others. The baker has bread and I don't, but I'm wealthy, so I can tell the baker "give me bread". Likewise I can tell a hairdresser to cut my hair. However, I cannot tell a driver to drive me around all day, because I am not wealthy enough for that. Someone who is ultra-rich can employ a personal driver, a cook and a maid, can tell others to work for them because there are people who are poor enough to accept the work. If everyone was equally wealthy, then no one would want to clean someone else's bathroom.

Comment: @Stef I don't think that is true. If everyone started equally wealthy, someone would still probably open a cleaning business to gain (or at least maintain) their wealth while others found other employment. And as an attorney I have turned down cases from people with more money than I that were fully prepared to pay my standard rate because I thought their case was unethical or I even just didn't want to work with them. That does suggest I have enough resources to be picky, which not everyone does, but someone with even vastly more wealth than I cannot necessarily command me.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I agree with every point you made in your comment and it appears to be completely aligned with my comment so I don't what it is that you don't think is true.

Comment: @Stef Unless I am misunderstanding your prior comment, I contradicted everything you said. You said wealth is the ability to command others. I said, wealth cannot be used to command, you can negotiate for services, but that is different. You said if wealth were equally distributed, one one would clean someone else's bathroom, I said yes a business to do that would still be built.

Comment: Oh, sure, you can win the contradiction game. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

Rich and poor are opposites in this particular case, so they are mutually exclusive, the same way as believers and non-believers.

But they are not mutually dependent or proportional, exactly like believers or Star Wars fans and non-fans. The existence of rich does not imply a similar amount of poor. As stated in another answer, rich/poorness do not follow a zero sum behavior.

Money represents the amount of participation in society. There are poor societies, where people do not interact too much and have a low participation. Other societies interact a lot and most people participate effectively, so they become, almost all, rich.

Another way to understand this phenomenon is by understanding money. A bill is a certificate of the debt that society has to someone. If I help others a lot I generate a lot of debt from them to me, and I get a lot of bills. The central bank of my country calculates the total amount of social debt and prints enough bills to cover such debt. My government is responsible for such bills to be honored when I present them to someone: if I want an apple, I get one of my certificates, give it to the tender in exchange. Legally, he's forced to accept it. If everybody helps the others, we get rich. If no one helps nobody, social debts decrease and people get poor.

In consequence, rich/poor is more a cultural /personal-interactive feature than a limited resources circulation behavior, which is clearly unfounded.

The notion of rich having "what belongs to the poor" is just founded on resentment and anger. You can increase taxes, forbid property, or put any other form of pressure over the rich, they will just leave your country, and even if their money remains, people will quickly consume it and become poor. A rich country is that which protect the rich.

Comment: While I agree with most of what you've said, I think it would be fair to acknowledge that what you describe is the ideal role of money, and in practice people often get richer by contributing ***less*** to society. For instance, if you have education in a scientific field, you can choose between a career in public research in a university, or a career in the private sector; the latter is much better paid, but you'll end up working for the benefits or a very small number of people at the detriment of society as a whole.

Comment: As a specific example, I have relations working on cancer research, some in universities, some for private companies. When a breakthrough happens in the university, it is immediately published in a scientific journal and becomes available to every university and private company in the world and results in a huge advancement for society as a whole. When a breakthrough happens in a private company, it is immediately protected by an NDA and results in consolidating the company's monopoly on expensive cancer treatments. Yet the researchers for private companies are much, much, much better paid.

Comment: @Stef there's no "ideal role of money". Money is a pragmatic fact. Now, there are rich that seem not contributing to society (e.g. a millionaire's sons, or who inherits a fortune). Yes. But they are at the head of a huge mechanism of social contribution. If you do public research, you might think such is a social contribution, but society doesn't consider it so; while being a professional football player is considered a huge contribution. You are right, but that is how money works. Remember the goal here is answering the OP, not justice or hate to the rich. See my profile for related issues.

Comment: You will always work for rich people, rich are the only who create jobs. And you decide if you want to work with them, because it is your decision. If you don't like it, just don't work for the rich. In general, if you work doing something you don't like, you will BECOME poor. While if you are happy, you don't need money anymore: you are rich: you have got enough money to buy all you need. (I've added a paragraph on my answer).